# Does D-Link DIR-600 support Tomato?

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

I saw D-Link DIR-600 supported DD-WRT firmware, but I can't find if it supports the Tomato firmware. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#what_will_this_run_on), no.

Comment: Bummer. I'm not a fan of DD-WRT.